# Creating instances of anonymous objects using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, orm, dapper

I'm in the process of learning Dapper and I'm having trouble creating instances of anonymous types with it. First of all, some context: we have a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Note that `T` can be anonymous.

```
IEnumerable<T> ExecuteCollection<T>(...)
{
    // Query building logic goes here.

    var statement = Something.Statement;
    var parameters = Something.Parameters;

    return _connection.Query<T>(statement, parameters);
}
```

This code works for registered classes like a charm. However, I want it to handle anonymous types as well, and the problem that is throw by the compiler is:

```
InvalidOperationException: "A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature ([signature of anonymous object]) is required for <>f__AnonymousType5`2[[System.Int16, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX]] materialization"
```

I know that the issue is the fact that anonymous objects have no constructors to work with. An alternative to that would be `(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), row)`, but the `row` variable must be an `object[]`, not a `DapperRow`.

Whenever I searched for information regarding this topic, everyone said that I shouldn't work with anonymous types to begin with. However, it is **required** that my function returns a collection of anonymous type items.

This is the first time I'm using Dapper, and I don't know whether I'm misunderstanding things or not. The question is: how can I create an instance of an anonymous object with Dapper, or what is the alternative around this problem so that my method can still return `IEnumerable<T>`? I'm using .NET Core.

Answer (score 3):

I think, unless I'm misunderstanding you just want to call

```
connection.Query(statement, parameters);
```

Without the generic arguments to do exactly what you are asking for to give you a dapper row. Then you can write

```
connection.Query(statement, parameters).Select(x => new { Something = x.Something});
```

To create an anonymous object.

Or to get a little more complicated you could convert to an expando object by casting the row to `IDictionary<string,object>`, and iteratively assigning the properties to an expando object.

Comment: That's what I have came up with so far. The problem is, I cannot hard-code properties in that ```new``` object, and I'm not sure how to iterate over both ```DapperRow``` and my type's properties programatically in order to rebuild the structure for the new object in an ```ExpandoObject```.

Comment: I think you can cast each row to (IDictionary<string, object>)