# How to collect data from multiple tables and create a typed object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dapper

I'm trying to retrieve data from multiple tables and create a typed objects (Class) for each query result (I can use **Dapper** reference).

Please find below my example:

```
List<ClassA> country = query<ClassA>(@"SELECT p.name, co.name, co.capital, co.area, co.population
                                       FROM t_person p
                                       INNER JOIN t_city c ON p.city_id = c.city_id
                                       INNER JOIN t_country co ON c.country_id = co.country_id");

List<ClassB> city = query<ClassB>(@"SELECT p.name, c.name
                                    FROM t_person p
                                    INNER JOIN t_city c ON p.city_id = c.city_i");

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCapital { get; set; }
    public decimal CountryArea { get; set; }
    public decimal CountryPopulation { get; set; }
}
```

For the first query, I need get all columns of **country** table and **only one** column from **person** table.
Should I get **Person object** or can I get a **typed object**?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return a `Person` object because none of your queries return a `Person`. If you want to return a typed object you need to define a type; for example for your first query:

```
public class PersonCountryResponse
{
    public string Person { get; init; }
    public string Country { get; init; }
    public string Capital { get; init; }
    public decimal Area { get; init; }
    public decimal Population { get; init; }
}
```

Then in your first select:

```
var pcrs = something.query(@"SELECT p.name AS personName, co.name AS countryName, co.capital, co.area, co.population
   FROM t_person p
   INNER JOIN t_city c ON p.city_id = c.city_id
   INNER JOIN t_country co ON c.country_id = co.country_id")
.Select(q => new PersonCountryResponse { Person = q.personName, Country = q.countryName, Capital = q.capital, Area = q.area, Population = q.population };
```

Comment: Hi @Richard, Thank you for your response! So, if I have another query that retrieves only Person, Country and Capital (Without Area and Population), I can't use PersonCountryResponse class because it's not a same need (Not a same object). Finally, I should create another class with 3 properties. In my case (My Job), we have more than 250 queries and each of them is unique (Different columns). Thank you!

Comment: @csharper, that is correct. You don't **have** to return a typed object. If you have many different queries you can use anonymous types directly from Dapper, like what I did with `q` above. Read [Create instances of anonymous objects using Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44067765/18978144).

Comment: I will see that! Thank you for your help! Have a good week-end!